# Help with sequence: $a_k = 5*3^k + 7*2^k$ - Induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Let $a_k$ be a sequence, where $a_0 = 12$, $\;$ $a_2 = 29$ and $a_k = 5a_{k-1} - 6a_{k-2}$ , $k\geq 2$ .

I need to prove, **using induction**, that $a_k = 5\times 3^k + 7\times 2^k \; , k\geq 0$ .

---

*Attempts at solution:*

I have tried strong induction, starting with $a_0 = 12 $ that is **true** according to the exercise.

Let $a_k$ be true, I tried solving for $a_{k+1}$ and trying to end up in something true again, so that I've got it proven.

No dice, I'm stumped by the $\times$ operations. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already done the base case, so try the inductive step.

Assume for all $\ell\le k$, the proposition holds.  Then $a_k=5\cdot3^k+7\cdot2^k$ and $a_{k-1}=5\cdot 3^{k-1}+7\cdot 2^{k-1}$.

So $$\begin{align}a_{k+1}&=5a_k-6a_{k-1}\\
&=5(5\cdot3^k+7\cdot2^k)-6(5\cdot 3^{k-1}+7\cdot 2^{k-1})\\
&=25\cdot3^k-10\cdot3^k+35\cdot2^k-21\cdot 2^k\\
&=15\cdot3^k-14\cdot2^k\\
&=5\cdot3^{k+1}-7\cdot2^{k+1}\end{align}$$
So the proposition holds for $a_{k+1}$

Comment: It's called Strong induction (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction)

Comment: Your help is very much appreciated, Tim.

Answer (score 1):

Note, however, that the induction step only holds for $k \geq 2$ so our base case should include checking $a_1$ as well.

Comment: I believe this would be better as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your note.

Answer (score 0):

In the induction step, after you use the induction hypothesis, you'll get an expression that's a sum of multiples of $3^{k-1}$, $3^{k-2}$, $2^{k-1}$, $2^{k-2}$. You'll be able to factor $3$s and $2$s out of some of the coefficients. Use that to bump up the exponents.